# how to fix type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' error

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to use a `gestureDetector` on **Text**, so I can change between home widgets, using `onGenerateRoute` parameter of `MaterialApp` Widget.

**gestureDetector over Text**:

[image: gestureDetector over Text]

**onGenerateRoute (Screenshot 1)**:

[image: onGenerateRoute]

**onGenerateRoute (Screenshot 2)**:

[image: ...continue]

Answer (score 2):

you should pass data with key value pair

change your _onLocationTap located in locations.dart to :

```dart
_onLocationTap(BuildContext context, int locationID){
  Navigator.pushNamed(context,LOCATIONDETAILROUTE,arguments:{"id":locationID});
}
```